# Part of my URL is being stripped away

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite

I've discovered that one of the sites on our web server is having part certain URLs stripped away. Specifically, when a user clicks the link to display images as a slideshow the URL for that page has `?show=slide` appended. Just that part is what is being stripped away.

Apart from this problem the site works correctly. Furthermore, the site used to work properly and I'm really not even sure at what point it broke, as I rarely visit it and the only thing that appears in my change log is updates to WordPress and its plugins.

I've confirmed that it's not caused by anything in the .htaccess file by installing an exact replica of the site on my dev server, from where it runs as expected. I've also duplicated the Apache virtualhost config for the site to the test server.

The only significant difference between the live and dev servers is that the former is Centos 5.5 and the other is Debian 6.0.

I'm stuck for ideas. If it's not the Apache virtualhost config or the .htaccess file, where else can I look for what might be causing this?

**Update**

Although to a mere human it did appear that part of the URL was being eaten up it turned out to be mod-rewrite and a 301 redirect. It was a case of misleading symptoms. The site in question runs WordPress with a number of plugins. The permalink rewriting for the main code and the permalink rewriting for one of the plugins didn't like each other and wouldn't play nicely together.

A bunch of uninstalling and reinstalling, together with turning permalinks off and on in various sequences finally got it all to work properly. As it happens, the part of the URL that was apparently disappearing was wrong anyway, resulting in a broken feature on the site.

Comment: Is the query string disappearing from the browser, or just not showing up on the server when the request lands?  And is the browser sent there directly by a link in HTML, or from a `30x` location header?

Comment: @Shane, it's disappearing at the server end and it's a direct link. I've even tested it with wget, just to be sure it's nothing odd at the browser end.

Comment: I'd say mod_rewrite is guilty until proven innocent; maybe capture a request with the `RewriteLogLevel` cranked up just to make sure?

Comment: @Shane, you're right. With logging cranked up it is showing a 301 on the request but I can't find what's causing it. Further investigation is needed but that will have to wait till the morning. Thanks.

Comment: @Shane, please post your comment as an answer. mod_rewrite is indeed the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_rewrite`, in the ballroom, with the candlestick.

Guilty until proven innocent indeed!  Maybe edit in some details of where the rule snuck in from and how you tracked it down?

Comment: Credit awarded and details added. I still find it odd that the same situation didn't occur on the mirror site.